# UITableView inside UIViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to use UITableView Inside UIViewController. However, when I tried to so it it gives me an error when I start the app.
the error says "method doesnt override ant method from superclass"

```
import UIKit

class GPATableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    struct Objects {
        var sectionName : String!
        var sectionObjects : [String]!
    }

    var objectsArray = [Objects]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        objectsArray =
        [Objects(sectionName: "Section1" , sectionObjects: ["","",""]),
        Objects(sectionName: "Section2" , sectionObjects: ["","",""]),
        Objects(sectionName: "Section3" , sectionObjects: ["","",""])]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell!
      //  cell?.textLabel!.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

        print
        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return objectsArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return objectsArray[section].sectionName
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you implement the `UITableViewDatasource` in an `UIViewController`, you are not overriding the methods.

Remove `override` from the methods that the compiler is tell you to.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell!
  //  cell?.textLabel!.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

    print
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return objectsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return objectsArray[section].sectionName
}
```

NOTE: If you were using a `UITableViewController`, then you would need the `override`, which is probably what was going on in whatever file you copied this from.

Comment: Thank you so much , your answer also very helpful. also the Note that you put is helpful.. thanks again !!

Answer (score 2):

Functions involving `tableView` such as `numberOfSections(...)`, `cellForRowAt` etc. are not part of the `UIViewController`.

Instead, they belong to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

To fix your errors, remove the `override` keyword in front of these functions. You are not overriding them but instead "implementing" them at the request of the protocols.

Be sure to also set the view controller as the `delegate` and `dataSource` if you have not already done so in a Storyboard:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // other code...

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // other code...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. your answer is very helpfull